# I don't get to see a preview of my PSD files in Finder

Tags: macos, adobe-photoshop, finder, osx-lion, photoshop-cs5

I used to be able to see previews of my Photoshop documents in Finder, both as an icon and with Quick Look. **Now, all .psd files just show a white box:**

[image: example]

How can I change this?

Comment: Does this happen to all PSD files? What happens if you re-save the files? I've seen very unpredictable behavior for those previews, some of my files have it, some don't.

Comment: All files, even after re-save.

Comment: Did you install a new OS since it worked?

Comment: Nope. This has been happening even before the Lion update.

Comment: Check "Maximize Compatibility," just try, for the heck of it. It's somewhere in File Handling preferences.

Comment: Nope. Nothing. :(

Comment: Can you still open them in Preview?

Comment: Do you have in Photoshop –> Preferences –> File Handling settings both Maximize Compatibility and Image Previews checked ?

Comment: @Kalessin - Nope, it shows nothing.

Comment: @harrymc - Image previews checked, Maximize compatibility checked. The little icon now shows the preview, but the actual preview (quick look) still doesn't show the preview.

Comment: Simply checking the Maximize PSD and PSB File compatibility worked for me (Yosemite 10.10.5, CC 2015)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First step : Go to Photoshop –> Preferences –> File Handling settings, and set both Maximize Compatibility and Image Previews to checked.

If that does not help, the article [FIX: Quick look on OSX not working (black box)](http://www.hamleshmotah.com/index.php/2010/01/14/fix-quick-look-on-osx-not-working-black-box/) suggests two solutions:

1. Select Utilities > Disk Utility, and then "Repair Disk Permissions". You will have to boot from the install media if you are repairing the same drive that your system boots from.
2. Reinstall the Mac OS X Update.

Comment: Well I'll be darned! Fixed! :D

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me. In Photoshop - Preferences - File Handling - DISABLE COMPRESSION OF PSD AND PSB FILES. I guess Finder doesn't like decompressing saved files to make a preview. It's funny though, I already do save with all preview images. But they barely work and usually fade out right after they appear.